# How to prove subsets of a function

Tags: functions

$ f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined as a one to one function.

For any collection of subsets $A_1, A_2, A_3 ......A_n$ prove that,

$$ f(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 ......A_n) = f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) \cap f(A_3) \cap ....f(A_n) $$

Is this proved like $ f(x_1+x_2+x_3...) = f(x_1) + f(x_2) + f(x_3) +.....  $ ? What should we get from it being one to one and A's being subsets?

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that you can do $f(x_1+x_2) = f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ so that is definitely not the reason!

Comment: Try to show for the case $n = 2$. You will have to show the two inclusions, namely $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$ and $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \supseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$. Then apply induction to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A_{1}\cap...\cap A_{n}\subset A_{k}$ for $k=1,...,n$ then $f(A_{1}\cap...\cap A_{n})\subset f(A_{k})$ for $k=1,...,n$.

So $f(A_{1}\cap...\cap A_{n})\subset f(A_{1})\cap...\cap f(A_{n})$.

Let $x\in f(A_{1})\cap...\cap f(A_{n})$ then $x\in f(A_{k})$ for all $k=1,...,n$. Since $f$ is injective then there is a unique $y$ so that $f(y)=x$. Considering the previous information we must have that $y\in A_{k}$ for all $k=1,...,n$. Hence, $y\in A_{1}\cap...\cap A_{n}$ and so $x\in f(A_{1}\cap...\cap A_{n})$.